# Sending email in laravel 5 not working

Tags: windows, laravel, email, ssl, laravel-5

After long searches in the forum, I can't find a helpful solution for my case. 
I did alot of functions for sending emails in laravel and always that works fine. 
This time, I got an error as you see below:

> ErrorException in StreamBuffer.php line 95:
>   stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Here my .env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:FMtA/k/okcPZB/HbWGbw5YiBM4EC3njxxLbgcdM1GrA=
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=myDB
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=suckerblood2010@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=<<Here_my_password>>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

MAIL_SENDER=Administration
```

Here my function to send the mail (in the controller Auth):

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    $token = hash('sha256', str_random(100) . time(), false);
    $user = new User();
    $user->email = $request->get('email');
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->get('password'));
    $user->remember_token = $token;
    //$user->save();

    $sent = Mail::send('auth.emails.createAccount', ['token' => $token], function ($m) use ($user) {
        $m->from(getenv('MAIL_USERNAME'), getenv('MAIL_SENDER'));

        $m->to($user->email, $user->email)->subject(config('constants.AccountCreated'));
    });

    if($sent == 1)
    {
        $msg = Lang::get('messages.EmailSent');
        $this->showLoginForm($msg);
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect('/login')->withErrors([
            'email' => Lang::get('messages.UserAddingError')
        ]);
    }
}
```

I tried to change the protocol from tls to ssl, even the prot from 587 to 465 
I have this problem only with this project and I can't understand why, despite all the searches I made...

Any suggestion please? 
Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

Your root certificate is missing or corrupted, try installing one

```
# 1) Download a valid root ca
http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

# 2) Setup php.ini to point it
openssl.cafile=C:\php5\etc\cacert.pem
```

To make sure they are loaded, review this console command response

```
php -r 'var_dump(openssl_get_cert_locations());
```

You may need to restart your webserver

---

You can also disable ssl peer verification in `php.ini`, but it is not recommend (**please don't do this in production!**)

```
openssl.verify_peer 0
```

*Useful docs: http://php.net/manual/migration56.openssl.php*

Comment: You can try to [install them](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/manage-trusted-root-certificates-windows) but your best bet is to disable peer verification

Comment: I can't disable it as you told me that's not recommend in production ...

Comment: You have production server on Windows 10?

Comment: I tried it online, it's working, just in local I get the problem ..
It's ok, thanks guys :)